# Multiple Spark Applications at same time , same Jarfile... Jobs are in waiting status

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Spark/Scala noob here.

I am running spark in a clustered environment.  I have two very similar apps (each with unique spark config and context).  When I try and kick them both off the first seems to grab all resources and the second will wait to grab resources.  I am setting resource on the submit but it doesn't seem to matter.  Each node has 24 cores and 45 gb memory available for use.  Here are the two commands I am using to submit that I want to run in parallel.

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://MASTER:6066 --class MainAggregator --conf spark.driver.memory=10g --conf spark.executor.memory=10g --executor-cores 3 --num-executors 5 sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar -new

./bin/spark-submit --master spark://MASTER:6066 --class BackAggregator --conf spark.driver.memory=5g --conf spark.executor.memory=5g --executor-cores 3 --num-executors 5 sparkapp_2.11-0.1.jar 01/22/2020 01/23/2020
```

Also I should note that the second App does kick off but in the master monitoring webpage I see it as "Waiting" and it will have 0 cores until the first is done.  The apps do pull from the same tables, but will have much different data chunks that they are pulling so the RDD/Dataframes are unique if that makes a difference.

What am I missing in order to run these at the same time?

Comment: How many nodes do you have in your cluster ?

Comment: @Srinivas I have 4 nodes in the cluster

Comment: check my answer Hope it helps. Similar situation I faced, more than one  timeseries jobs successfully  came out using fair scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> second App does kick off but in the master monitoring webpage I see it
>   as "Waiting" and it will have 0 cores until the first is done.

---

I encountered the same thing some time back. Here there are 2 things..

May be these are the causes.

1) You dont have proper infrastructure.

2) You might have used capacity scheduler which doesnt have preemptive machanism to accommodate new jobs until it.

If it is #1 then you have to increase more nodes allocate more resouces using your `spark-submit`.

If it is #2 Then you can adopt hadoop fair schedular where you can maintain 2 pools  [see spark documentation on this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html) advantage would be you can run parllel jobs Fair will take care by pre-empting some resouces and allocate to another job which is running parllely.

- `mainpool`  for the first spark job..
- `backlogpool` to run your second spark job.

To achive this you need to have an xml like this with pool configuration
sample pool configuration :

```
<pool name="default">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>3</weight>
    <minShare>3</minShare>
</pool>
<pool name="mainpool">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>3</weight>
    <minShare>3</minShare>
</pool>
<pool name="backlogpool">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>3</weight>
    <minShare>3</minShare>
</pool>
```

Along with that you need to do some more minor changes... in the driver code like which pool first job should go and which pool second job should go.

***How it works :***

[image]

For more details see the articles by me..

[hadoop-yarn-fair-schedular-advantages-explained-part1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hadoop-yarn-fair-schedular-advantages-explained-part1-ram-ghadiyaram/)

[hadoop-yarn-fair-schedular-advantages-explained-part2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hadoop-yarn-fair-schedular-advantages-explained-part2-ram-ghadiyaram/)

Try these ideas to overcome the waiting. Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you!  So I RTFM and found that I had missed this: spark.cores.max which when i set that on the application submit they ran in parrellel just fine.  However, manually setting the max cores is not the way to go, so I am going to go with the pool route and see if I can maximize cluster resources for both jobs.  Thanks for the directions.  I'll mark accepted if I can get the pool running.

Comment: pools is concept in scheduling. it should work. [chcek spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html)